# Qt QProcess intermittent failure to read stdout

Tags: qt, multiprocessing, stdout, qprocess

I have a really simple usage of QProcess:

```
void MainWindow::startPing()
{
    auto p = new QProcess(this);

    connect(p, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, this, &MainWindow::procStdout);
    connect(p, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int)>(&QProcess::finished), this, &MainWindow::procFinished); // workaround for overloaded 'finished' name

    p->start("C:\\windows\\system32\\ping.exe", "127.0.0.1");
}

void MainWindow::procStdout()
{    
    ui->textEdit->append("readyReadStandardOutput");
    auto msg = p->readAllStandardOutput();
    ui->textEdit->append(QString::fromUtf8(msg));
}

void MainWindow::procFinished()
{
    ui->textEdit->append("finished");
}
```

The subprocess prints a few lines of stdout a few seconds apart, and then closes. (Ping used by example; i have another app i need to read its stdout)

This code has worked 100% of the time on thousands of machines. But recently I found one PC where it's really, really unreliable.

On this affected machine, the **first** time you run this code in a Qt app, ping.exe appears in Task Manager; but *no `readyReadStandardOutput` signals are emitted*. Eventually the `finished` signal is emitted.

If you try it 2-5 more times, it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't.

After about the 5th time it's perfectly reliable.

The issue affects also synchronous use of QProcess (i.e. `QProcess::waitForReadyRead`).

Is there something wrong with the code above that could be causing this? Or is this likely to be caused by a Qt bug (5.6 LTS)? Or is there any possible aspect of the affected PC that would explain this behaviour?

I tried connecting the signals by `Qt::QueuedConnection` and `Qt::DirectConnection` with no change in result.
I tried connecting to the stderr and `QProcess::errorOccurred` signals too, but there were no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably related to [QTBUG-67744](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67744), related to QProcess and stdout pipes.

Upgrading to Qt 5.11.2 resolved the issue on the affected machine.